# cannot deploy MERN to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mern

I'm having a problem deploying my MERN app to heroku, the process faild to react scripts, I've deployed 2 apps before using the same config and postbuild script, also, there is an app that I deployed before with no problem, tried to deploy it again to a new app on heroku just to test things and it fails.

I'm on windows 10 64x by the way, node 10.15.1, npm 6.4.1

```
  {
  "name": "recipury",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app to add food recipes",
  "main": "server.js",
 "scripts": {
  "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
  "start": "node server.js",
  "server": "nodemon server.js",
  "client": "npm start --prefix client",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
  "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix 
   client && npm run build --prefix client"

 },
 "author": "abed taki",
 "license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
 "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
 "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
 "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
 "express": "^4.16.4",
 "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
 "mongoose": "^5.4.4",
 "multer": "^1.4.1",
 "passport": "^0.4.0",
 "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
 "validator": "^10.10.0"
 },
"devDependencies": {
 "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
 },
 "engines": {
  "node": "10.15.1",
  "npm": "6.4.1"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using error handling in server.js then try to move the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/buil')));` before calling error